# Get Atom to read $PATH from shell

Tags: shell, atom-editor

`$PATH` can be read by [Atom](https://atom.io/) on each file, by setting `process.env['PATH'] = {{PATH_here}}`. This is useful to use plugins like linters, that rely on system-installed binaries.

However, my `$PATH` isn’t completely set in my `.zshrc`. I use [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), and [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), which dynamically set their directories on my `$PATH` every time I open a shell (due to some configurations in my `.zshrc`).

This makes it so I can’t simply [load `$PATH` from my .zshrc](https://gist.github.com/dustinblackman/db56445e5d649ccbd2b2): the file has to be interpreted and the commands started, for the full `$PATH` to be determined.

Something like `/usr/local/bin/zsh -c "source ${HOME}/.zshrc && echo $PATH"` was my first bet, but that doesn’t work. Is there a way to accomplish this at all?